# setup.py: Copy file to root python directory

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a python library which depends on a DLL. For better deploying I'd like to write a `setup.py` for easily installing via `python setup.py install`. The mentioned DLL needs to be inside the python root directory, for example `C:\Python32\`. Is this possible using setuptools?

Comment: Why the Python root directory? I'm pretty sure that's not the right place. :-)

Comment: The developer of the DLL said it should be there. If I put it there manually the python lib works. Where should I put the DLL else?

Comment: Depends on what DLL it is, and other things. Putting it there will work, sure, but that's awfully messy. But I'll leave this to Windows experts.